# About Linear Mappings and Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question:**  If $L : V → W $is a linear mapping and $\{L(v_1), \dots, L(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent.

**Proof:**

**1.**$\{L(v_1), ... L(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent implies $d_1L(v_1) + \cdots+ d_nL(v_n) = 0$ only has the trivial solution.

**2.** This can be rewritten as $L(d_1v_1 + \cdots+ d_nv_n) = 0$.

**3.** Since linear mappings send zero to zero, we have $d_1v_1 +\cdots + d_nv_n = 0$, where the only solution is the trivial solution.

**4.** Thus $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is linearly independent.

I'm not sure if I can go from steps 2 to 3 because the $d_1 ,... ,d_n$ represent any real numbers, and since the equation has changed, the $d_1, ..., d_n$ could also change to match the new equation and are no longer all zeros.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have that $d_1v_1 + \cdots +d_nv_n \in \text{Nul}(L)$, but you can't immediately say that $d_1v_1 + \cdots + d_nv_n = 0$. It might be easier to check the contrapositive, i.e. if $\{v_1, \dotsc, v_n\}$ is a dependent set in $V$, then $\{L(v_1), \dotsc, L(v_n)\}$ is a dependent set in $W$.

Comment: Could you give any tips on how to prove this statement?

Comment: Start with a nontrivial linear combination $d_1v_1 + \dotsc +d_nv_n = 0$ where not all the $d_i = 0$. Apply $L$, use linearity, and see what you get.

Comment: but why can't i go from L(d1v1+...+dnvn) = 0 to d1vn+...+dnvn=0?

Comment: Take the linear transformation $L : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $L(x,y) = x$. You can check this is linear; however, any vector of the form $(0,y)$ will be mapped to $0$. This is one example where you cannot conclude that $L(x,y) = 0  \implies (x,y) = (0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

The step is allowed if the transfomation is injective that is $L(x)=0 \implies x=0$.

For further details refer to [Showing that a one-to-one linear transformation maps a linearly independent set onto a linearly independent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70876/505767).

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments,  start with $d_1v_1+\dots +d_nv_n=0$.  Then use $L(0)=0$ and linearity to get $d_1L(v_1)+\dots +d_nL(v_n)=0$.  Then by linear independence of the $L(v_i)$, the $d_i$ are all zero...

Comment: but why can't i go from L(d1v1+...+dnvn) = 0 to d1vn+...+dnvn=0?

Comment: As @gimusi points out,  this is true if $L$ is injective;  but not in general (some linear transformations have nontrivial kernel...).

Comment: For instance,  consider a projection.   Besides,  in this problem you start by assuming you have a linear combination of the $v_i$ equal to zero:   there's no need to prove it...